# Extra data from a json payload and display it

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a website that recieves data from an api and displays it. Here is my code:

```
 // on my component 
 this.products$ = this.store
  .select(selectDealsProductsByPriorities(this.priorities))
  .pipe(
    map((res) => res.data),
    map((a) => ({
      // what goes here???
    }))
  );



 //the json object with just one of the items
 {
   "timeStamp": "2024-01-20T12:43:36.022277300",
   "statusCode": 200,
   "status": "OK",
   "message": "success",
   "data": {
     "products": [
       {
        "product_id": 67,
        "shop_id": 12,
        "category_id": 9528,
        "product_ident": "56-790-0882",
        "ident_type": "EAN",
        "product_name": "project",
        "age_group": "18-24"
        ...
      }
    ]
  }
}


// the interface has a lot of items so ill cut some of it out
export interface IProduct {
   product_id: number
   shop_id: number
   category_id: number
   product_ident: string
   ident_type: string
   product_name: string
   age_group: string
   brand_name: string
   ...
}
```

Now my issue is that I don't know how to extact only the products array in the data object so that I can loop through it in the front end.

Also if it helps, I am using ngrx(maybe the data can be extracted in the effects or reducers??). Here is a sample of the ngrx code:

```
    // an effect
    getAllProducts$ = createEffect(()=> {
    return this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(GET_ALL_PRODUCTS),
        switchMap(action => {
            return this.productsSvc.getProducts().pipe(
                map(res => GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS({products: res.products})),
                catchError( error => of(GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_ERROR({error: error?.error?.message})))
            )
        })
    )
})


 // a reducer
 const productsReducer = createReducer(
initialState,
on(GET_ALL_PRODUCTS, (state) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        allProducts: {
            ...state.allProducts,
            status: 'loading',
            error: null
        }
    }
}))
```

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've managed by changing the ngrx effect to so:

```
   getAllProducts$ = createEffect(()=> {
    return this.action$.pipe(
        ofType(GET_ALL_PRODUCTS),
        switchMap(action => {
            return this.productsSvc.getProducts().pipe(
                map(res => GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS({products: res.data.products})),
                catchError( error => of(GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_ERROR({error: error?.error?.message})))
            )
        })
    )
})
```

The `GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS`   action is now recieving `products: res.data.products`. I have also gotten rid of the pipe in the component.